# issue in stringifying a list or list of list in python and converting it back to original form

Tags: python, list

I have been trying to `stringify` a `list` and `list of list` and then convert it back to it's original form. Following are my 2 sample `lists`:

```
option_list = ['1309', '1P09', 'Bdg 1', '1226', 'Bdg 1']
option_listoflist = [['1309', 'Blg 1', 500], ['1P09', 'Bdg 1', 4501], ['1226', 'Bdg 1', 600], ['1302', 'Bdg 1', 1432]]
```

I wrote this `python` code, based on some SO posts, where I am trying to `stringify` the above 2 `lists` and then try to convert them back but it is throwing error:

```
str1 = ''.join(option_list)
print(str1+'\n')
str_2_list = ast.literal_eval(str1)
print(str_2_list)

str2 = ''.join(option_listoflist)
print(str2+'\n')
str_2_listoflist = ast.literal_eval(str2)
print(str_2_listoflist)
```

When I execute this I get `invalid syntax` error at `str_2_list = ast.literal_eval(str1)`.

How can I `stringify` a `list` and `list of list` and then convert it back to it's original form?

**NOTE:**  What I want to do is to convert `['1309', '1P09', 'Bdg 1', '1226', 'Bdg 1']` to string version like this `"['1309', '1P09', 'Bdg 1', '1226', 'Bdg 1']"` and then convert it back to original list. Similarly for a list of list

Comment: With your method of converting a list to a string, how would you tell the difference between `['ab', 'c']` and `['a', 'b', 'c']` (both are turned into `abc`)? What exactly are you trying to do with this approach?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` doesn't perform black magic, as @Blender is asking you about.

Comment: @Blender What I want to convert `['1309', '1P09', 'Bdg 1', '1226', 'Bdg 1']` to string version like this `"['1309', '1P09', 'Bdg 1', '1226', 'Bdg 1']"` and then convert it back to original list

Comment: Ah! But you should have been able to figure out that `''.join(option_list)` outputs `'13091P09Bdg 11226Bdg 1'` by running it. From there, it's clear that `ast.literal_eval` is not the problem.

Comment: @user2966197: What are you going to do with the string version of this list? There are many ways of serializing objects. No single approach is the best.

Comment: @Blender I want to use string version in  `string-to-string maps of attributes and values` and then reconstruct the list from string version

Comment: @user2966197: So you just want to use these lists and lists-of-lists as keys in a dictionary?

Comment: @Blender as values not keys. So like `session_attribute['list1'] = <string version of list>`. Something for this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/context-mgmt.html#context-mgmt-complex-attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be trying to replicate JavaScript's `JSON.stringify`, just use the `json` module to do exactly that:

```
In [1]: import json

In [2]: option_list = ['1309', '1P09', 'Bdg 1', '1226', 'Bdg 1']

In [3]: option_listoflist = [['1309', 'Blg 1', 500], ['1P09', 'Bdg 1', 4501], ['1226', 'Bdg 1', 600], ['1302', 'Bdg 1', 1432]]

In [4]: json.dumps(option_list)
Out[4]: '["1309", "1P09", "Bdg 1", "1226", "Bdg 1"]'

In [5]: json.dumps(option_listoflist)
Out[5]: '[["1309", "Blg 1", 500], ["1P09", "Bdg 1", 4501], ["1226", "Bdg 1", 600], ["1302", "Bdg 1", 1432]]'

In [6]: json.loads(json.dumps(option_list)) == option_list
Out[6]: True

In [7]: json.loads(json.dumps(option_listoflist)) == option_listoflist
Out[7]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong - conversion to string. Try `str1 = str(options_list)`

Answer (score 0):

Your `''.join(option_list)` outputs `'13091P09Bdg 11226Bdg 1'` which can't be converted to list because the output string is not following list syntax.

Crrected Code

```
option_list = ['1309', '1P09', 'Bdg 1', '1226', 'Bdg 1']
option_listoflist = [['1309', 'Blg 1', 500], ['1P09', 'Bdg 1', 4501], ['1226', 'Bdg 1', 600],['1302', 'Bdg 1', 1432]]
str1 = ','.join(option_list)
print(str1+'\n')
str_2_list = str1.split(',')
print(str_2_list)

str2 = ','.join(str(item) for innerlist in option_listoflist for item in innerlist)
print(str2+'\n')
str_2_listoflist=[str2.split(',')[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(str2.split(',')), 3)]
for i in str_2_listoflist:
  i[2]=int(i[2])
print(str_2_listoflist)
```

> Output:
>
> 1309,1P09,Bdg 1,1226,Bdg 1
>
> ['1309', '1P09', 'Bdg 1', '1226', 'Bdg 1']
>
> 1309,Blg 1,500,1P09,Bdg 1,4501,1226,Bdg 1,600,1302,Bdg 1,1432
>
> [['1309', 'Blg 1', 500], ['1P09', 'Bdg 1', 4501], ['1226', 'Bdg 1',
>   600], ['1302', 'Bdg 1', 1432]]

Comment: This does not properly reconstruct the second list.